# Understanding use of Generics within the java collection class

Tags: java, generics, collections, types

After looking into Java's Collection class (OpenJDK 8_update40), I found the following method:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
     T candidate = i.next();

     while (i.hasNext()) {
         T next = i.next();
         if (next.compareTo(candidate) > 0)
             candidate = next;
     }
     return candidate;
}
```

I don't fully understand the use of generic types here. As far as I understand has T to be a subtype of Object which also has to implement the Comparable interface which is also parameterized via a generic parameter. The parameter of Comparable states that is have to be some supertype of T. Due to that we have some kind of recursive type definition.

But here is my question: As far as I know every type in Java is a subtype of Object, so why do they specify
it within the definition of T?

Comment: why Object bound - short answer - backward compatibility. don't worry about it, you don't need to care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for backwards compatibility reasons.

When you use a generic type and this generic type has lower bounds, such as:

```
<T extends Foo & Bar> void someMethod(T xxx)
```

then the runtime signature of `someMethod` will be:

```
void someMethod(Foo xxx)
```

(well, OK, the argument name is not there, but you get the picture).

Now, `Collections.max()` was defined *before* JDK 5; and its signature was:

```
public static Object max(Collection coll)
```

which, in Java 5, could be translated as:

```
public static Object max(Collection<Object> coll)
```

The thing is that the return value of `max` cannot be a `Comparable`...

---

Of course, in this case, more difficulties are added:

- the second lower bound it *itself* a generic type;
- moreover `Comparable` is a "consumer" in the PECS way (hence `Comparable<? super T>`);
- the `Collection` passed as an argument can have any type which is either `T` or anything extending `T`, hence `? extends T`; we don't care about the actual type, only that the `Collection` is guaranteed to return something which is *at least* a T.

This explains the somewhat convoluted signature...

Comment: While the backward compatibility issue is what the OP’s question is about, I tried to imagine how a scenario needing all of these `extends` and `super` clauses looks like, I couldn’t find one. It would require an explicit type argument matching neither the actual `Comparable` implementation nor the type of the `Collection` to exploit these possibilities. But there is no imaginable reason to insert such an explicit type argument. So at least the `? extends ` in the `Collection<? extends T>` parameter type is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger not sure what you mean here; this method does require that a type parameter be defined as a return type. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can always infer the most specific type for `T`, i.e. the collection’s element type, and use that type as the method’s return type. It will still be assignable to every supertype of `T`. That’s why `Collection<T>` is sufficient, widening the type of the returned element is always possible. By the way, this always happens when `T` is inferred by the compiler. That’s why I said, you need to insert an explicit type witness, not matching the collection’s element type, to exploit the current flexibility. But there is no use case for that…

Answer (score 0):

Because if you dont use the "T" the collection would only accept instances of Object.

For example String is subtype of Object, but would not compile because the collection would only accept Object instances.

Comment: I know what generics are used for, but this doesn't answer my question. My point is, that <T extends Comparable<? super T>> should be enough

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [covariance vs. contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

As a general rule:

- If a generic type T is used to return values, then you use `<? extends T>` as in Iterator
- If a generic type T is used to accept values, then you use `<? super T>` as in Comparable

Comment: I believe the op's question was more about "why Object"; but as to what you describe this is pretty much PECS. Right?

Comment: I guess I misread the question. Yes, that is what I'm describing.